# Center hrule in the middle of the page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules

I would like to center a horizontal line on my page and I would like the width of this line to be half `\textwidth`. Here is what I tried but it doesn't work :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

Hello everyone ! 

\begin{center}
\hrule width 0.5\textwidth
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: `\rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.5pt}`?

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @karlkoeller `\rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.4pt}` is a better equivalent to `\hrule`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it seems it doesn't produce a line centered on the page.

Comment: @lockstep Yes, you're right, `0.4pt` is the exact equivalent, according to the TeXbook.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can replace

```
\hrule width 0.5\textwidth
```

with

```
\rule{0.5\textwidth}{.4pt}
```

Also, if you don't need the `center` environment for anything else, you can replace

```
\begin{center}
\rule{0.5\textwidth}{.4pt}
\end{center}
```

with simply

```
\noindent\hfil\rule{0.5\textwidth}{.4pt}\hfil
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

Hello everyone !

\begin{center}
\rule{0.5\textwidth}{.4pt}
\end{center}

\noindent\hfil\rule{0.5\textwidth}{.4pt}\hfil

\end{document}
```

Output

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `\rule` in the accepted answer, but I ended up going with `\hrule` like the original question asked too:

```
\newcommand{\SectionBreak}{%
    %\vskip 0.5ex

    \nointerlineskip
    \moveright 0.125\textwidth \vbox{\hrule width0.75\textwidth}
    \nointerlineskip
    %\vskip 0.5ex
    \makeatletter
        %\@afterindenfalse%
    \makeatother

}
```