# Rule at the end of chapter: vertical and horizontal aligning

Tags: rules

I want to place in the end of the chapter a short horizontally centered line, aligned vertically in the proportions of 2:3.

Everything works except of the horizontal alignment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\clearpage

\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\vspace{\stretch{2}}

\begingroup\centering

\hrule width .25\textwidth height .5pt

\endgroup

\vspace*{\stretch{3}}

\clearpage

\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Consider replacing the TeX macro `\hrule` by LaTeX `\rule{width}{height}`. See e.g. [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128636).

Comment: @campa, yes, I tried but now vertical stretching doesn't work correctly with \rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `\rule` is set at the bottom of a text line, so it is lower than you might think.  thus, you need to raise it so that it is vertically centered on that
(otherwise invisible) line.

this formulation of the `\rule` command (ending with `\par` to ensure that it
is just one line) comes close.  the `[1ex]` is the amount the rule is to be
raised.

```
\rule[1ex]{.25\textwidth}{.5pt}\par
```